# How to build a Query Layer in ArcMap 10.1 using columns of two different databases?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, sql-server

As you may know, to create a Query Layer in ArcMap 10.1, it is required to **specify a connection to a concrete database** and then, define the access to the tables and columns in the SQL Query associated.

It turns out that in my query **I need to access columns in the Master system database**, such as **master.dbo.spt_values.number**, but once I am connected in ArcMap 10.1 to the database where to perform the query, can I access system databases and use its fields in my query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any matching attributes common in both databases? or is this a purely a spatial query?

Comment: Not really. In fact, that table to be queried does not have a spatial column: I will join that query layer in ArcMap afterwards. You know: "old" databases, difficult to apply GIS analysis.